# Codeigniter validation required show event when the field is not empty

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor

[image: Error ckedotr]

Codeigniter validation required show event when the field is not empty.

UPDATE:

I using ajax and jquery to get the data. So I solve the problem by using this

```
$('#form_post_topic').submit(function(event){
              event.preventDefault();
            var value = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();

              $.ajax({
            url: 'write_validation',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                category: $('#category').val(),
                content: value,
                tags: $('#tags').val()
            },
```

Comment: Check in browser console value of variable `value`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have this
view.php

```
<form action ="validate_form" mehotd="post">
    <label>Topic Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="tname" value="<?= set_value('tname');?>"><br>
    <label>Select Category</label>
    <select name="category">
        <option value="1" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', TRUE); ?> >category 1</option>
    </select><br>
    <label>Content</label>
    <textarea name="content" placeholder="write some content"><?= set_value('content');?></textarea><br>
</form>
```

controller.php

```
function validate_form(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tname', 'Topic Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }
}
```

**The important thing is the name in textarea**

Comment: Hi, did you use a tuto like [link](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Helper-for-CodeIgniter-PHP), you need to use this `echo form_ckeditor(array('id'=>'textarea_id', 'name' => 'name'));` The problem is not Ckeditor, is the form that you validate that input (name)

Comment: It really is Ckeditor. I solve the problem by using this.  var value = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I am also getting  data with use of this code.

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();
```